# nativescript - change variable on exitEvent

Tags: nativescript

I need to be able to change some variable's value, when app is closed.
I'm using exitEvent described here:
https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle

Also, i'm using local-storage plugin that works similar to javasctip's localstorage.
https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-localstorage

My simple code looks like this:

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
require("nativescript-dom");
var LS = require("nativescript-localstorage");
const application = require("tns-core-modules/application");
var page = require("ui/page");

exports.load = function (args) {

var page = args.object;
var model = new Observable();
var frame = require('ui/frame');
var ff = frame.getFrameById("dashboard");
var topmost = frame.topmost();

// This is exit event
application.on(application.exitEvent, (args) => {
    LS.setItem('XX','111')
});


// What i will exit app, and run app again this will newer become 111,
it's null all the time
console.log(LS.getItem('XX'));
}
```

So, my question is - is possible to set any flag on app exit - it do not have to be localstorage (i've tested global variables to), to detect if exit was made, and based on this i can make a decisions that will help me ?

One of scenarios may be - i'm holding some flag in Localstorage that is TURE is user tapped "rememebr me" on the login screen.
So on exit i can check if he want's to be rememebered, if not i want to send user to login page and not dashboard when app is lauching....

Thank you.

EDIT:
I've tried applications-settings too, it will not work.

```
application.on(application.exitEvent, (args) => {
    applicationSettings.setString("Name", "John Doe");
});


console.log(applicationSettings.getString("Name")); // not working
```

Comment: Is it iOS or Android you are testing with?

Comment: Hi Manoj, It's IOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's the issue with the `nativescript-localstorage` plugin. It writes the changes to file [after a 250ms delay](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-localstorage/blob/master/src/localstorage.js#L37). At exit event you will give you very limited amount of time before your app is completely killed by system.

May be the Author had a reason for setting up this delay but I think its too much of time at least in this particular scenario so the changes are never written to file. You may raise a issue at the plugin's Github repo.

If you are looking for an immediate workaround, copy `localstorage.js` to your app and export `internalSaveData` from the file, so you could directly call it right after you finish setting your values.

Comment: Looks like you're right - sometimes this value is saved, sometimes not. So the delay makes sense. Thank you.